# Changing background image src periodically using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, background

I'm trying to have the background image of the body of my page change every (approximatly) N seconds. For this i have a PHP function that echoes random image src when i call it using AJAX. I then replace the current body background image src by this newly generated one, but i can't get it to work.

Here is the code, is there anything wrong in it ?

```
(function($) {

    var $body = $('body');

    window.setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/some_path/index.php?exec=getNewBkgImgSrc',
        }).done(function(data) {
            var newImage = new Image();
            newImage.onload = function() {
                $body.css('background-image', newImage.src);
            };
            newImage.src = data;
        });
    }, 5000);

})(window.jQuery);
```

And the PHP function which does work :

```
public function getNewBkgImgSrc() {
    echo CONTENT_URL_DIR.'/Wallpapers/wallpaper ('.rand(1, 20).').jpg';
}
```

Could this be because i'm using localhost ? I can mremeber having AJAX problems before when i was developping locally.

EDIT : A clue maybe is that the style property of the body element doesn't sseem to change / be set in Firebug. I also tried `$('body').first()` and `$(document.body)` and using `url("")` (in the value of background-image property) but it doesn't work either. The onload event does fire however.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you creating a new image object if you are getting a URL back from PHP?  Just set the background-image property of body to:

```
$body.css('background-image', "url('" + data + "')");
```

If using vanilla JS:

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('" + data + "')";
```

See proper format for that property here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Yes i also tried using url() and url('') and url(""), but none worked. I tried your solution (putting the URL directly) but it does not work either :(

Comment: Well i added simple quotes insides the url() of your solution and it does work now. I was using an image to avoid the white blink while the image is loading. Thanks for your help. EDIT: Actually only the vanilla js solution works.

Answer (score 0):

might need to cache bust the ajax call. Try changing the url property of the ajax call to 
'/some_path/index.php?exec=getNewBkgImgSrc&cb='+((new Date).getTime()).

Answer (score 0):

I have not good sense about `var $body = $('body');`

use `$('body').css('background-image', newImage.src);`